# PostgreSQL two-table constaint not working properly

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I run the following code:

```
-- Table describing messages
CREATE TABLE messages
(
 id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 text TEXT  -- Message can have or not have text
);

-- Table describing media attached to messages
CREATE TABLE messages_attachments
(
 message_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES messages,
 -- Messages can have any number of attachments, including 0
 attachment_id TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- Messages must have either text or at least one attachment
CREATE FUNCTION message_has_text_or_attachments(integer) RETURNS bool STABLE
AS
$$
 SELECT
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM messages_attachments WHERE message_id = $1)
 OR
  (SELECT text IS NOT NULL FROM messages WHERE id = $1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

ALTER TABLE messages ADD CONSTRAINT nonempty_message CHECK ( message_has_text_or_attachments(id) );

-- Insert a message with no text and no attachments. Should fail, but it does not
INSERT INTO messages(text) VALUES (NULL);

SELECT *, message_has_text_or_attachments(id) FROM messages;
```

I expected it to fail on the `INSERT` line because the row being inserted violates the check constraint (we are inserting a message which's text is `NULL` and there are no attachments for that message), but it runs successfully and the next query returns (`1`, `NULL`, `false`) (here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/322c3/1) with slightly modified function definition (apostrophes instead of dollar symbols because of the database version).

One more interesting thing is that if I change the order of the commands and `INSERT` the row before adding the `CONSTRAINT`, then PostgreSQL fails to `ALTER` the table, because "`check constraint "nonempty_message" is violated by some row`".

Why does PostgreSQL allow inserting the row, which violates the constraint? Am I mistaken somewhere in the function definition? Is there some limitation on how constraints can be applied and which tables can they depend on? Is it a PostgreSQL bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html):

> PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table data other than the new or updated row being checked. While a CHECK constraint that violates this rule may appear to work in simple tests, it cannot guarantee that the database will not reach a state in which the constraint condition is false (due to subsequent changes of the other row(s) involved).